# Unable to install npm package from gitlab registry

Tags: javascript, typescript, medusa

I published npm package to gitlab package registry. I think it was successful, but I am unable to install package into another project.

`Npm install` gives me following error:

```
PS E:\faq\medusa-1.16> npm install medusa-plugin-static-pages-testing
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/medusa-plugin-static-pages-testing - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'medusa-plugin-static-pages-testing@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: If you mean that you published package to gitlab's package registry, did you follow steps in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/#install-a-package ? You need to login into registry and download from it, currently you are trying to install from default public registry.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm way off base, I apologize, but (from your post) it sounds like believe publishing your code on gitlab makes it available as a public package in the `npm` library (which it does not)---`gitlab` is ("just") a git repository (well, it's more, but for your current purpose that's sufficient).

I think you want to check out `npm-publish` (available under the `npm cli`). Some instructions [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-publish).

Comment: Gitlab offers private npm registry - see docs at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/